# How to debug an external view function call that reverts?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I know that it is possible to debug a transaction, but external views don't use a transaction as far as I know, and while calling this function, I keep getting the following error message:

```
 'missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string',
```

(I'm using hardhat and the same code runs ok when running on the hardhat network)

Comment: Hard to help you without the code.

Comment: Yeah but I want a generalized solution on how to debug external view calls.

Comment: I use remix to debug step by step.